# rsync with iCloud folders

Tags: bash, rsync

I'm trying to set up a workflow to copy my iCloud script projects to my user library. Sadly apple decided to add quite a few unfriendly characters in the file path.

```
rsync -aE –delete ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~ScriptEditor2/Documents/Script\ Libraries/ ~/Library/Script\ Libraries/
```

I keep getting. The following error:

```
rsync: link_stat "/Users/{{my_username}}/\#342\#200\#223delete" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-54/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
```

The file is truncated so I feel it's a parse error, but I can't get it to work. I've tried a few different ways of writing the path, but they all are saying the path does not exist.

Comment: Your rsync command shows a different directory than in the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Your `delete` option is wrong. It should be `--delete` with 2 ASCII "minus" characters.

I suspect you may have a character encoding problem. Rich text editors and word processors often combine `--` to an "emdash" character. The error message shows it is trying to access a file with some non-ASCII characters followed by "delete". This shows that `rsync` is treating the `delete` part as a file path instead of a command flag.